# ColdFusion: Replacing String with a cfdocumentitem tag

Tags: pdf, replace, coldfusion, cfdocument

I have following situation: I create a PDF with the cfdocument tag but the documents value is generated by some other cf functions. Now I need some pagebreaks at specific points but it logically won't work with the cfdocumentitem (pagebreak) tag because it is not nested in a cfdocument tag. I tried to mark the points where I need these pagebreaks with a specific string and replace them somehow with the cfdocumentitem tag.. but as expected it doesn't work..

```
<some function>
  <table>blablahtml</table>

  <cfif pdfreport>markedforpagebreak</cfif>

  <table>blablahtml</table>
  .
  .
  .
</some function>

<other function>
  <cfdocument>
    #replace(dashboardHTML,"markedforpagebreak","<cfdocumentitem type='pagebreak'/>","all")#
  </cfdocument>
</other function>
```

I also looked at evalAtPrint attribute but it doesn't work either.. so has anybody an idea to solve my problem?
Thanks =)

Comment: My idea is cfsavecontent.

Comment: What is your code doing? Are you seeing the string `<cfdocumentitem type='pagebreak'/>` in your PDF document?

Comment: @DanBracuk dashboardHTML is a cdsavecontent in which I call "<some function>"

Comment: @Miguel-F No, I still see "markedforpagebreak"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with replace.

We use a special character to denote pagebreaks.  Then treat the content as a list, with this character as a delimiter.  Then loop through the 'list', and for each iteration of the loop, display the chunk of text, and then insert the cfdocumentitem tag  e.g.

```
<cfdocument>
<cfset numPageBreaks = listlen(email_message_text,'¶') />
    <cfloop from="1" to="#numPageBreaks#" index="thisPageBreak">
        #listgetat(email_message_text,thisPageBreak,'¶')#
        <cfif thisPageBreak lt numPageBreaks>
         <cfdocumentitem type="pagebreak" />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfdocument>
```

Comment: It's a very good idea but sadly it still does not work.. now the specialcharacter is displayed but not a pagebreak..

Comment: Works for us... try a really simple delimiter first to rule out any encoding issues.  (e.g. an asterisk).  Then check that the numPageBreaks is giving you the expected value.  If it does, this should work.

Comment: Ouch.. I did a terrible mistake.. I have a replace before that to affect some other stuff and I did not save the new content to a variable.. so I worked with the old one ... Thanks a lot!